# OSGi BundleListener and BundleTracker in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, osgi, equinox

I have trouble listening for OSGi bundles entering RESOLVED state in Eclipse RCP. Neither BundleListener or BundleTracker seems to notice bundles entering RESOLVED state.

Listeners does however notice the RESOLVED to ACTIVE event. Is it possible that bundles part of a launch configuration enter RESOLVED state before listener bundles have a chance to register themselves?

One more thing, I thought that bundles would lazily/automatically go from RESOLVED to ACTIVE as soon as other bundles (for example) tried to access their services/classes?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible for all bundles to become RESOLVED before any bundle is activated. A bundle has to be activated to get control so that is can register a BundleListener or open a BundleTracker.

A RESOLVED bundle can load classes without being ACTIVE. If a bundle is marked for lazy activation, then the 1st class load from the bundle can trigger activation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is a way to force ACTIVE state on certain bundles before others enter RESOLVED?

Comment: That is not, in general, possible. With a ResolverHook, you could get notified when a bundle is about to be resolved. And the hook could attempt to start some other bundle. But that might not work well. For example, if both bundles are part of the same resolve operation.

I think you should reconsider why you want to do this since it seems like a bad design with brittle dependencies.